# Cannot change line color in MATLAB plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

No matter what I specify as the colors of my lines on this MATLAB plot, the resulting plot displays this automatic coloring:

[image]

here is the code I used:

```
figure 

plot(cumsum(sign([y_pred]).*tst_y)/std(sign([y_pred]).*tst_y), 'g')  
xlabel('Time'); 
ylabel('Cumulative Returns (%)');          
title('Neural Network Model Returns')
hold on 

plot(cumsum(tst_y)/std(tst_y),'r')

hold off
```

I have tried different methods of specifying the color and even attempted to edit line color in the graph editor. Any idea how I can make these lines different colors? I am using Matlab 2016a trial version

Comment: I can not reproduce this behaviour. This type of colouring seems quite unusual to me. Does a simple `figure, plot([1 3 2],'r')` have the same problem on your system?

Comment: This may be an artifact of using the trial version to ensure that you don't publish the resulting figures without paying for the product.

Comment: @AlexanderBüse it didn't occur when attempting a simple plot like the one you suggested - however I solved it for my plot by increasing the line width from (what must have been) its default of 0.5 to 1.5. After doing this, the color specifications I wrote would show up on the graph, whereas before nothing would change! I was in need of a quick fix so didn't experiment to understand the problem better - any ideas?

Comment: No, sorry I don't have any ideas, why this could be. I think @Suever 's comment is a good hint.

Answer (score 0):

Neither I can replicate your issues. Perhaps the data in y_pred or tst_y is not a simple double-class (perhaps something specific to the neural network toolbox?) and therefore has a differently defined plot function in matlab.

Otherwise you should be able to try

```
figure 

pl=plot(cumsum(sign([y_pred]).*tst_y)/std(sign([y_pred]).*tst_y));
pl.Color='g';
xlabel('Time'); 
ylabel('Cumulative Returns (%)');          
title('Neural Network Model Returns')
hold on 

pl=plot(cumsum(tst_y)/std(tst_y));
pl.Color='r';

hold off
```

Comment: you could also run `whos y_pred tst_y` to see if they are of some weird data-type?